# Unexplained Padding to ELF Section

Tags: gcc, alignment, padding, offset, elf

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the ELF format. To do this, I wrote a small C file called share.c and from that created a shared object called share.so. Below is the contents of share.c:

```
static int count = 0;

void increment()
{
     count++;
}
```

Below is the command I used to create share.so:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -o share.so share.c
```

I used the readelf tool to look at both the program headers and the section headers within share.so. Below are the program headers in share.so:

```
Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x550
There are 7 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x00000000000006f4 0x00000000000006f4  R E    200000
  LOAD           0x0000000000000e30 0x0000000000200e30 0x0000000000200e30
                 0x00000000000001f0 0x00000000000001f8  RW     200000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000000e48 0x0000000000200e48 0x0000000000200e48
                 0x0000000000000190 0x0000000000000190  RW     8
  NOTE           0x00000000000001c8 0x00000000000001c8 0x00000000000001c8
                 0x0000000000000024 0x0000000000000024  R      4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0000000000000674 0x0000000000000674 0x0000000000000674
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000000e30 0x0000000000200e30 0x0000000000200e30
                 0x00000000000001d0 0x00000000000001d0  R      1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .init .plt .plt.got .text .fini .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   01     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   02     .dynamic 
   03     .note.gnu.build-id 
   04     .eh_frame_hdr 
   05     
   06     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .dynamic .got
```

Below are the section headers in share.so:

```
There are 27 section headers, starting at offset 0x1820:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE             00000000000001c8  000001c8
       0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 2] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH         00000000000001f0  000001f0
       000000000000003c  0000000000000000   A       3     0     8
  [ 3] .dynsym           DYNSYM           0000000000000230  00000230
       0000000000000138  0000000000000018   A       4     2     8
  [ 4] .dynstr           STRTAB           0000000000000368  00000368
       00000000000000ad  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 5] .gnu.version      VERSYM           0000000000000416  00000416
       000000000000001a  0000000000000002   A       3     0     2
  [ 6] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED          0000000000000430  00000430
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       4     1     8
  [ 7] .rela.dyn         RELA             0000000000000450  00000450
       00000000000000c0  0000000000000018   A       3     0     8
  [ 8] .init             PROGBITS         0000000000000510  00000510
       000000000000001a  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [ 9] .plt              PROGBITS         0000000000000530  00000530
       0000000000000010  0000000000000010  AX       0     0     16
  [10] .plt.got          PROGBITS         0000000000000540  00000540
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     8
  [11] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000000550  00000550
       0000000000000116  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
  [12] .fini             PROGBITS         0000000000000668  00000668
       0000000000000009  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [13] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS         0000000000000674  00000674
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [14] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         0000000000000690  00000690
       0000000000000064  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [15] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY       0000000000200e30  00000e30
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [16] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY       0000000000200e38  00000e38
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [17] .jcr              PROGBITS         0000000000200e40  00000e40
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [18] .dynamic          DYNAMIC          0000000000200e48  00000e48
       0000000000000190  0000000000000010  WA       4     0     8
  [19] .got              PROGBITS         0000000000200fd8  00000fd8
       0000000000000028  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [20] .got.plt          PROGBITS         0000000000201000  00001000
       0000000000000018  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [21] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000201018  00001018
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [22] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000201020  00001020
       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     4
  [23] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00001020
       0000000000000034  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [24] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  0000173b
       00000000000000e4  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [25] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00001058
       0000000000000528  0000000000000018          26    44     8
  [26] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00001580
       00000000000001bb  0000000000000000           0     0     1
```

With this information, I can see that the ELF header and the program headers constitute the first 0x1C8 bytes of the file, which is why the first section (.note.gnu.build-i) starts at offset 0x1C8. The reported offsets for all the sections up to but not including .init_array make sense when you take the alignment requirements into account.

What does not make sense to me is the offset for the section .init_array. The alignment requirement for this section is 8 bytes and the end of the previous section (.eh_frame) is at offset 0x6F4. This would seem to imply that the next section should be located at 0x6F8 (4 bytes of padding). However, readelf reports that the .init_array section starts at offset 0xE30.

I thought that perhaps there was some other section of useful information inserted in this unexpected gap, but hexdump shows nothing but null bytes. This leads me to believe it is some sort of padding. The alignment requirement of the LOAD segment containing  the .init_array segment doesn't seem to explain this padding. Part of the map file created by the linker for this shared object is below:

```
.eh_frame       0x0000000000000690       0x64
 *(.eh_frame)
 .eh_frame      0x0000000000000690       0x40 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
 .eh_frame      0x00000000000006d0       0x20 /tmp/ccDzwTL8.o
                                         0x38 (size before relaxing)
 .eh_frame      0x00000000000006f0        0x4 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtendS.o
 *(.eh_frame.*)

.gcc_except_table
 *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*)

.gnu_extab
 *(.gnu_extab*)

.exception_ranges
 *(.exception_ranges .exception_ranges*)
                0x0000000000200e30                . = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (0x200000, 0x1000)

.eh_frame
 *(.eh_frame)
 *(.eh_frame.*)

.gnu_extab
 *(.gnu_extab)

.gcc_except_table
 *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*)

.exception_ranges
 *(.exception_ranges .exception_ranges*)

.tdata
 *(.tdata .tdata.* .gnu.linkonce.td.*)

.tbss
 *(.tbss .tbss.* .gnu.linkonce.tb.*)
 *(.tcommon)

.preinit_array
 *(.preinit_array)

.init_array     0x0000000000200e30        0x8
 *(SORT(.init_array.*) SORT(.ctors.*))
 *(.init_array EXCLUDE_FILE(*crtend?.o *crtend.o *crtbegin?.o *crtbegin.o) .ctors)
 .init_array    0x0000000000200e30        0x8 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbeginS.o
```

The line with the comment ". = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (0x200000, 0x1000)" also doesn't seem to explain this padding. I would expect the value of the location counter to be 0x00000000002006F8.

Does anyone with more experience with the details of the ELF format have an explanation for this unexpected padding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have discovered where the padding is coming from. According to this [page](http://nairobi-embedded.org/040_elf_sec_seg_vma_mappings.html), the AMD64 toolchain provided with Ubuntu is likely to use the -z relro option as a default. This explains why there is a GNU_RELRO entry in the program headers table. The built in default linker script contains a DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END(offset, exp) directive before the .got.plt section. According to this [page](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Builtin-Functions.html):

> When ‘-z relro’ option is not present, DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END does
>   nothing, otherwise DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN is padded so that exp + offset
>   is aligned to the most commonly used page boundary for particular
>   target

This would explain why the offset of the .got.plt section is aligned to the nearest page (0x1000). The sections from .init_array to .got are therefore placed at the end of the previous page which introduces the mysterious padding after the .eh_frame section.

The GNU_RELRO entry in the program header table and the padding disappear when share.so is built using the following command:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-z,norelro -o share.so share.c
```